# $\cot(x)\,$ in the large $x$ limit?

Tags: asymptotics, trigonometric-series

I couldn't find asymptotic forms of trigonometric functions in any Math Table.

In particular, I am trying to find $\;\cot(a x)\;$ in large $x$ limit.

thanks,

Comment: $\cot(x)$ is a periodic function with period $\pi$ and blows up at $k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. $\cot(ax)$ does not have any asymptotic expansion for large $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Notw that $cot(x)$, with period $\pi$, is periodic.

To see this, it helps to remember that $\;\cot(ax) = \dfrac{\cos(ax)}{\sin(ax)},\;$ and recall what happens to $\cot x\,$ each time $\,x \to k\pi,\;k \in \mathbb Z:$

$\qquad\qquad\quad \text{Graph of}\;\;{\bf f(x) = \cot x}$

$\qquad\qquad$[image]

and hence, what happens as $\,ax \to \dfrac {k\pi}{a}.\;$ (For $|a| > 1$, the period decreases, for $|a| < 1$, the period increases.)

> Note: $\quad\cot(ax)\,$ does ***not*** have any associated asymptotic expansion for large values of $\,x$.

Comment: Good for you! Feel free to answer your own question! I didn't realize you were dealing with $z \in \mathbb C$, and considering $\text{Im}\,(z) \to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

for

$$z = x + iy$$
and as 
$$y \to \infty$$
we have the following series representation
$$cot(z) = -i[1+2 \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \exp(2 i k z) ]$$
and once you set $$x$$ to 0, this helps you to get an asymptotic form for $cot(z)$ as $z \to \infty$.